# PHP, PDO bindValue - how to pass comma seperated INTs string for use with IN clause

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query like this:

```
$get_articles  = "SELECT ..... WHERE c1.category_id = :main_category AND c2.category_id IN (:answers)...."
```

**main_category** is one number, so it is not a problem,
**answers** is a string that looks like this: 
'71','101','145','43','95','45','113','139','73','65','119','149','55','63','151'

when I change **:answers** to **$answers** everything works fine, so obviously it's my problem.

I found info that I must bind each value.
unfortunately number of elements in string and values is not constant. So is there any way to bindValue without doing it for each value separately?

Thanks!

Comment: You will need to replace each and every one with a placeholder.

Comment: Likely `$answers` can be passed to the `execute` then you just need a placeholder for each value. `str_repeat` can do that.